# What is the word that describes the fumes and oils carried in them that are given off naturally by certain trees

Tags: terminology

When one walks near certain evergreen trees, many times the scent of turpentine can be smelled --- likewise, the natural oils that are evaporating in to the vicinity.

Comment: This question needs a sample sentence where you would use the word, otherwise it will be closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

Fragrant and Odiferous Trees  [enter link description here](https://gabrielhemery.com/fragrant-and-odiferous-trees/) a blog

> Trees are beautiful to the eye but their smell is often overlooked. I
>   don’t mean the obvious showy flowering trees but the hidden olfactory
>   wonders in leaf, bark and seed. Here are my favourite Fragrant trees,
>   and some less popular Odiferous trees.

**fragrant**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fragrant)

> Having a pleasant odor.

**odiferous**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/odiferous)

> Having or giving off an odor, not necessarily pleasant

This article discusses and lists trees, both pleasantly fragrant and those less so, the odiferous.  The smell is from the trees themselves, not their flowers. A term to include both could be the **scent** (odour or fragrance) of trees.

Answer (score 2):

**Balsamy** is one.

Balsam:

> 1a : an aromatic and usually oily and resinous substance flowing from various plants
>   especially : any of several resinous substances containing benzoic or cinnamic acid and used especially in medicine
>
> b : a preparation containing resinous substances and having a balsamic odor
>
> 2a : a balsam-yielding tree especially : BALSAM FIR

"Balsam." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 8 Dec. 2018.

also, the related word *balm*, although it isn't as often used with Western Hemisphere conifers.

> 4 : a spicy aromatic odor
>   … the white lilies in the garden, the herb bed near the bees—everything sent out fragrance and balm into the soft air …
>   — Agnes S. Turnbull

"Balm." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 8 Dec. 2018.

> It was a pretty road, running along between snug farmsteads, with now and again a bit of balsamy fir wood to drive through or a hollow where wild plums hung out their filmy bloom. The air was sweet with the breath of many apple orchards and ...

*Ann of Green Gables* by Lucy Maud Montgomery - 1935

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the object itself that is the oil and the fragrance, you could say you're referring to the ***essence***. The oils are often referred to as ***essential oils***, and the fragrance given by them can also be called an ***essence***.

According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/essence) under definition 4:

> ***essence***
>   *noun*
>   es·​sence | *\ˈe-sᵊn(t)s*\
>
> 1a : the permanent as contrasted with the accidental element of being
>
> b : the individual, real, or ultimate nature of a thing especially as opposed to its existence
>   *a painting that captures the essence of the land*
>
> c : the properties or attributes by means of which something can be placed in its proper class or identified as being what it is
>
> 2 : the most significant element, quality, or aspect of a thing or person the essence of the issue
>
> 3 : one that possesses or exhibits a quality in abundance as if in concentrated form she was the essence of punctuality
>
> **4a(1) : a constituent or derivative possessing the special qualities (as of a plant or drug) in concentrated form**
>   *also* : a preparation of such an essence or a synthetic substitute
>
> (2) : a volatile substance or constituent (as of perfume)
>
> **b : odor, perfume**
>
> 5 : something that exists : entity